# Checking sql errors/exceptions

Tags: sql, database, exception, crud

When I use java, I've often seen code like this:

```
try {
    // any CRUD operation
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // do some specific database error stuff
    // if we're in a transaction, we usually rollback
    try {
        // rollback the transaction
    } catch(anotherException e) {
        // do some specific rollback error stuff
    }
}
```

I only encountered sql/database errors when there are things very wrong with my code. Doing SQL operations and putting try catches around them seems very very repetitive.

Since it is good practice to validate user input on the server side, what is the need for catching database exceptions besides connecting to the database at the start of your application?

Comment: Programming is very very repetitive.    You should probably also have a finally block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing *any* external software system, you should be checking for errors this is just good practice.  Although "normal" operations may not generate an error, you can get errors for other reasons.  For example:

- The database server drops the connection.
- The database/schema/table is no longer available.
- The query generates a time-out.
- The database log is full.

You can also get errors if the underlying database changes.  For instance:

- Column types might change.
- Column names might change.
- Table names might change.

The point is:  Either you are writing throw-away, one-time code or you are writing sustainable code.  If the latter, then you should be checking for potential errors.  The `try`/`catch` blocks are a sign of responsible programming and good practice.  They are not clutter.

Comment: good points. If such errors occur in my application, I should write a separate error page for this because these errors come from the server, right?

Comment: @morbidCode . . . Probably something like that -- you need to decide how you handle the errors.

Answer (score 1):

More an answer to your question on the answer from Gordon.  But too much for a comment.

What you do with the exception depends on the level of the exception.  User does not really care if the error came from the server or client. All they care about is it did not work.

If you can deal with it gracefully then give the user a warning message in a consistent manner.  It can be on the same page, another page, pop-up...  Can continue.  A timeout is an example of non-critical error.

If it is a fatal error then give the user a message of fatal error again in a consistent manner and shut the application down.  Typically tell them to call tech support.  Correct, a user does not like to see a critical error message but that is better then the app just crashing out.

A good practice is to write the exception, inner exceptions, time, and userID to the database so you can better deal with it.  Stuff is going to break in test and production.  Without good exception handling it is much harder to track down and fix bugs.  I think it is less work to just do it right up front.  If it is a throw away utility then another thing.